# How to delay a next call rxjs

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have an observable `canContinue: Subject<boolean>`. I want to call next after a 100ms delay, how would you do this in rxjs?

ex: `this.canContinue.wait(100).next(true);`

I could use setTimeout but if rx has a way built in I would prefer to use it instead.

Edit: Ya sorry, it should be a Subject instead of an Observable.
The delay operator kinda does what I want but I add that when I subscribe.

`this.canContinue.delay(100).subscribe(s => //do something)`
But that will delay every time, I only want to delay sometimes.

In my use case I have a button that will take you to another set of options in a form, but selecting an option will automatically take you to the next option, but I want a delay because its jarring to instantly see the next options.

Comment: `Observables` don't have a `next` method, that is `Observers`.  I assume you want `delay` but it is hard to say without knowing what you are trying to accomplish with this.

Answer (score 0):

as @paulpdaniels pointed out, your example is a bit wrong, so i'm trying to infer what you want. There are several ways to delay the emission of an element. This will delay only the emission of `true` elements.

```
Rx.Observable.of(true,false,true).mergeMap(value => {
  return value === true 
  ? Rx.Observable.of(value).delay(100)
  : Rx.Observable.of(value);
}).subscribe(console.log);

false
true
true
```

This will delay everything:

```
Rx.Observable.of(true,false,true).delay(100).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: I added some context to try and explain what i'm doing better @mkulke

Comment: @Devcon > But that will delay every time, I only want to delay sometimes.

Comment: @Devcon: What does _sometimes_ actually mean? Is it dependant on the emitted value, in this case the solution above should work: `mergeMap` and then, depending on the value, return the Observable or and Observable w/ an delay. If _sometimes_ depends on some other entity in your program, you probably should wrap that entity in an Observable as well and use `withLatestFrom(otherEntity$, ...)`, and use that for filtering the observable.